# How do I make an equation to be dimensionally consistent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, dimensional-analysis

> Velocity is related to acceleration and distance by the following expression:
>   $$v^2=2ax^P$$
>   Find the power P that makes this equation dimensionally consistent.

$$\frac{v^2}{2a}=x^P$$
$$P={\log_x (\frac{v}{2a})}$$

and I am clueless what to do after that.
Please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$v$ has the units of $L\cdot{T^{-1}}$

$a$ has the units of $L\cdot{T^{-2}}$

$x$ has the units of $L$

$(L\cdot{T^{-1}})^2=(L\cdot{T^{-2}})\cdot{}L^P$

$L^2\cdot{T^{-2}}=L^{(P+1)}\cdot{T^{-2}}$

Comparing terms,

$2 = P + 1 => P = 1$

Answer (score 0):

x is position  $x$ $[L]$
v is velocity $\frac{\delta x}{\delta t}$ $[L][T]^{-1}$
a is acceleration $\frac{\delta v}{\delta t}$ $[L][T]^{-2}$

forget the constant factors ( 2 has no dimension )
from $v^2 = a \cdot x^P$  we get   $[L]^2[T]^{-2}=[L][T]^{-2}[L]^{P}$  or $[L]^2=[L]^1[L]^{P}$
then $[L]^2=[L]^{1+P}$
 valid when $P=1$
then the valid expression is $v^2=2 a x$

Comment: sorry, I was late and it is similar to the other answer.